# R Function can't find an object provided as an argument

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function that takes a data frame, performs a survival analysis for each gene (columns), and prints the significant survival curves. My data looks like the following with dog names as rownames and genes as column names, with the last 2 columns being disease free interval (DFI, the survival time metric) and if the sample should be censored (1) or not (0).

| Dog Names | Gene 1 | Gene 2 | DFI | Censor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dog 1 | High | Low | 130 | 0 |
| Dog 2 | Low | High | 88 | 1 |

I have multiple data frames of dogs so I wish to make a function to avoid retyping the same code. The following code works when I run it on its own but when I try to create a function with it I get an error.

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
survPlot <- function(x){
  s <- Surv(x$DFI, x$Censor)
  for (i in 1:(ncol(x)-2)){
    n_high <- length(which(x[,i] == "High"))
    n_low <- length(which(x[,i] == "Low"))
    sfit <- survfit(s ~ x[,i])
    pval <- surv_pvalue(sfit, data = as.data.frame(x))$pval
    if (pval <= 0.05){
      abc <- ggsurvplot(sfit, data = as.data.frame(x[,i]), pval = T, title = colnames(x)[i], legend.labs = c(paste0("High Expression", "\n", "n =", n_high), paste0("Low Expression", "\n", "n =", n_low)))
      print(abc)
    }
  }
}
survPlot(mydata)
```

I get the error  `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'x' not found` but x is the argument in the function so I don't understand what is happening.

**Edit

Here is a sample of my data

```
mydata <- structure(list(`cfa-miR-142` = c("High", "Low", "High", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low"), `hsa-miR-133b` = c("Low", 
"High", "Low", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low"
), `hsa-miR-20a-5p` = c("Low", "High", "Low", "High", "High", 
"High", "High", "High", "High", "High"), `hsa-miR-19a-3p` = c("High", 
"Low", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", 
"High"), `hsa-miR-222-3p` = c("Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low"), `hsa-miR-451a` = c("Low", 
"High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
"High"), `cfa-miR-221` = c("Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
"Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low"), `cfa-miR-1` = c("High", "Low", 
"High", "Low", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "Low"), 
    `hsa-miR-185-5p` = c("Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
    "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low"), `hsa-miR-145-5p` = c("High", 
    "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", 
    "Low"), DFI = c(99, 1008, 238, 861, 277, 285, 26, 277, 591, 
    415), Censor = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c("Dog_1", 
"Dog_2", "Dog_3", "Dog_4", "Dog_5", "Dog_6", "Dog_7", "Dog_8", 
"Dog_9", "Dog_10"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please post your sample data using `dput()` so we can copy/paste into R for testing? The formula you are using is probably just capturing the wrong environment.

Comment: That is because a formula contains symbols and environment in which the symbols are to be obtained from. So when you do `survfit(s ~ x[,i])` the formula stores the symbol `x[,i]` hence it will search for `x` and in this case, `x` cannot be used as a argument.  You probably should consider using the names of the dataframe. eg `for(i in head(names(x), -2))`  then change the `survfit(s ~ x[,i])` to `survfit(reformulate(i, 's'))`

Comment: `survfit(reformulate(i, 's'), data = x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These functions seem to be pretty picky. It doesn't look like they tolerate non-standard column names very well. I've added in `make.names()` to ensure that column names are valid variable names. I've also used a different method to build the formula. Try this

```
survPlot <- function(x){
  names(x) <- make.names(names(x))
  for (i in 1:(ncol(x)-2)){
    n_high <- length(which(x[,i] == "High"))
    n_low <- length(which(x[,i] == "Low"))
    form <- eval(bquote(Surv(DFI, Censor)~.(as.name(names(x)[i]))))
    sfit <- do.call("survfit", list(form, data=quote(x)))
    pval <- surv_pvalue(sfit, data=x)$pval
    if (!is.na(pval) & pval <= 0.05){
      abc <- ggsurvplot(sfit, data=x, pval = T, title = colnames(x)[i], legend.labs = c(paste0("High Expression", "\n", "n =", n_high), paste0("Low Expression", "\n", "n =", n_low)))
      print(abc)
    }
  }
}
survPlot(mydata)
```